# Flutter use TextEditingController on another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i class witch contains two text editing controllers one for the email and one for the phone number, on the other file i need to fetch data from the api and for basic authentication i use these two text editing controllers, the problem is that i need to use these two text editing controllers on my function witch im fetching data from but i get an error since i dont have the text editing controllers on that file, i wanted to know a way on how to use these two text editing controller on the other file. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
}

other file

Future<List<LoginData>> fetchLoginData() async {
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/employees';

  String basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
      base64Encode(
        utf8.encode('${emailController.text}:${passwordController.text}'), // error here
      );
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
  );
  print(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    List data1 = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    return data1.map((data) => LoginData.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load LoginData');
  }
}

class LoginData {
  final String loginPhoneNumber;

  LoginData({
    required this.loginPhoneNumber,
  });

  factory LoginData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginData(loginPhoneNumber: json["phoneNumber"].toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: your method fetchLoginData() should have parameters, so it'll be fetchLoginData(String email, String password)

Comment: Future<List<LoginData>> fetchLoginData(TextEditingController emailController, TextEditingController passwordController), if i do this would it be the same text editing controllers as i used in the LoginScreen class

Comment: in the future Builder when passing the function is asking for a getter to the parameters

Comment: 1. why would you pass controllers, not just text? 2. I can't see where is your future builder and what it does.

Comment: oh okay, yeah i did that, only one problem left, in the file where i have the futurebuilder i pass the function with two parameters in the future, but i get the error that the two parameters are not defined, and they need a getter, so would i remove the error on the two parameters of the function

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of `GetX Controller` and using that you can easily get access to any value/controller at any file of your app.
You need to add [GetX](http://get:%20%5E4.6.1) to `pubspec.yaml` if haven't added it.

Now, to archive what you want, just make a separate file and create a class that should be `initialized` with GetX Controller. Just like this:

```
class TextControllers extends GetxController{

  Rx<TextEditingController> emailController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> passwordController = TextEditingController().obs;
  
}
```

Then define the GetX Controller where you want to use it, like this way:

```
final TextControllers textControllers = Get.put(TextControllers());
```

Next, set to controller to your `TextField`, this way:

```
TextFormField(
   controller: textControllers.emailController.value,
   decoration: const InputDecoration(
   label: Text('label')
 ),
),
```

Now you can get the controller value like this:

```
Text(textControllers.emailController.value.text,)
```

Now you can access your controllers anywhere you want!